# How to parse env variable in a quoted string?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I'm having a hard time getting the value of an environment variable (`$GHREPO`) in a quoted string. Here is the command I'm running. I'm trying to make a directory with the value of 
`j["ChgSub"][$GHREPO][0]["Major"]`, $GHREPO being an environment variable.

```
 mkdir `cat ../dummy.json | 
 ruby -rjson -e 'j = JSON.parse($stdin.read); puts j["ChgSub"][$GHREPO][0]["Major"].to_s'`
```

Edit:
dummy.json content

```
{

  "ChgSub": {
    "ecx": [
      {
        "Major": 0,
        "Minor": 0,
        "Patch": 3
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Variables don't get evaluated in a single quoted string. You need to use double quotes. If you can't or don't want to use double quotes for the whole string you can use them for just that part of the string.

```
ruby -rjson -e 'j = JSON.parse($stdin.read); puts j["ChgSub"]["'"$GHREPO"'"][0]["Major"].to_s'
```

That is three separate quoted strings next to one another.

```
'j = JSON.parse($stdin.read); puts j["ChgSub"]["'
```

and

```
"$GHREPO"
```

and

```
'"][0]["Major"].to_s'
```

Comment: It still errors out so I can only assume the environment variable is not correctly parsed because if I replace it with the actual string it works. `mkdir `cat dummy.json | ruby -rjson -e 'j = JSON.parse($stdin.read); puts j["ChgSub"]["'"$GHREPO"'"][0]["Major"].to_s'`

Comment: @mihai What is the value of `GHREPO`?

Comment: A string... "ecx". I've updated the question with the json content as well. To reproduce the issue you need to set ``export GHREPO=ecx`` and run the command

Comment: @Etan, I finally got it though have my vote anyway as it's close to your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should always avoid mixing languages as much as possible. In this case you are trying to mix shell script into ruby script. Mixing languages convolutes your code and makes it fragile.

The solution in this case is to use ruby's native environment variable support.

```
$ GHREPO=ecx ruby -rjson -e 'j = JSON.parse($stdin.read); puts j["ChgSub"][ENV["GHREPO"]][0]["Major"].to_s' < dummy.json
0
```

To make this even clearer, I would use a heredoc, and not a quoted argument:

```
$ export GHREPO=ecx
$ ruby -rjson - dummy.json <<'EOF'
> j = JSON.parse(File.read(ARGV[0]))
> puts j["ChgSub"][ENV["GHREPO"]][0]["Major"].to_s
> EOF
0
```

Using a heredoc, you no longer have to fight with embedding single quotes within double quotes, escaping, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `'"'$GHREPO'"'`  so the command is

```
cat dummy.json | ruby -rjson -e 'j = JSON.parse($stdin.read);
   puts j["ChgSub"]['"'$GHREPO'"'][0]["Major"].to_s'
```

@Etan was pretty close to the answer.

Comment: This generates the same output as mine only it uses single quotes on `['exc']` instead of double quotes `["exc"]`. echo both the ruby command strings to see that.

Comment: Not really...  `'"'$GHREPO'"'` is not same as `"'"$GHREPO"'"` . The ruby command starts a single quoted string  `rjson -e 'j =` and that's why your solution fails.

Comment: `'...['"'$BAR'"']...'` is `'...['`, `"'$BAR'"`, `']...'` which evaluates (when `BAR=exc`) to `'...['`, `"'foo'"`, `']...'`. Which when pasted together and unquoted becomes `...['foo']...`. `'...["'"$BAR"'"]...'`, in contrast, is `'...["'`, `"$BAR"`, `'"]...'` -> `'...["'`, `"exc"`, `'"]...'` -> `...["exc"]...`.